# Indian Passport Holder travelling to South Korea - visa requirements

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, south-korea

I am an Indian Passport holder who is working in Bangkok, Thailand (Work permit holder)

1. Do I need Tourist Visa for South Korea?
2. Do I need Business visa for South Korea in case of meeting the client or Branch office in South Korea?

Answer (score 2):

Ordinary Indian passport holders will need a visa to visit South Korea.

Ministry of Foreign affairs:  http://www.mofa.go.kr/ENG/visa/application/index.jsp?menu=m_40_10